# How does PowerPoint distinguish which script out of latin/eastasian/complexscript is used for a Run?

Tags: c#, fonts, powerpoint, openxml

I stumbled upon an issue when trying to count the number of characters displayed with each font in the Presentation in PowerPoint via Open XML.
A single Run can contain RunProperties, which can have multiple fonts declared for LatinFont, EastAsianFont and ComplexScriptFont.
My questions is: how exactly PowerPoint determines which out of the above fonts will be used for a given set of characters. 
Could it be that within one Run there could be multiple fonts displayed?
Could those perhaps be presented as Unicode ranges?
Thank you in advance for your insight!

I am trying to avoid assigning the same characters for multiple fonts when counting them. How should I count space for example if there are 2/3 fonts declared for a Run?

```
<a:r>
<a:rPr lang="pl-PL" dirty="0" smtClean="0">
    <a:latin typeface="Courier New" panose="02070309020205020404" pitchFamily="49" charset="0"/>
    <a:cs typeface="Forte" panose="03060902040502070203" pitchFamily="66" charset="0"/>
</a:rPr>
<a:t> </a:t></a:r>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font switches based on the language with which the run is marked. This PowerPoint XML displays text in the Latin, Complex Script and East Asian fonts of the font theme. Please note the **lang** tag for each:

```
<p:txBody>
    <a:bodyPr/>
    <a:lstStyle/>
    <a:p>
        <a:r>
            <a:rPr lang="en-US"/>
            <a:t>English</a:t>
        </a:r>
        <a:endParaRPr lang="ar-KW" dirty="0"/>
    </a:p>
    <a:p>
        <a:r>
            <a:rPr lang="ar-KW" dirty="0"/>
            <a:t>ِقشلاهؤ</a:t>
        </a:r>
    </a:p>
    <a:p>
        <a:r>
            <a:rPr lang="th-TH" dirty="0"/>
            <a:t>ธ้ฟร</a:t>
        </a:r>
    </a:p>
</p:txBody>
```

Comment: Thank you John!
Do you know when the ComplexScript language is triggered then?
Is there any mapping of language code -> font theme?

Comment: PowerPoint has a hard-coded list of which language codes are Complex Script, which are East Asian and which are Latin, then chooses the font specced in the font theme. For a user to enter Complex Script or East Asian text, they normally have to set a suitable language input in their operating system, or set the File>Options>Language>Editing Language preferences in their copy of Office for Windows.